# Prevent text wrapping within an element

Tags: html, css

How can you force text within an element to not wrap, and have the element's width still determined by its contents (instead of manually setting width)?

**Example:**

On this page you can see a green button with the text "Get Started". For smaller screen sizes, the text wraps.  How can I prevent this?

https://pleth-test.herokuapp.com/

I tried using `overflow` and `text-wrap` CSS properties, but couldn't get anything to work.

Comment: At 10.6k, you should probably know what makes for a good question. Which is to say, code in the question itself, not on a third party site.

Comment: At 4k, you should probably know that opening a comment with a condescending statement isn't appreciated. Which is to say, you can just say the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

`white-space:nowrap` or `white-space:pre`.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I agree, will be careful in future